# Open Source personal dashboard web application

Tags: open-source, web-apps, note-taking, self-hosted, rss

I've been using websites like [Netvibes](https://www.netvibes.com/en) and [start.me](https://start.me/en) as personal dashboards for a while.

They are fine, but I'm now looking for an open source alternative that I could host myself on a server and occasionally modify/extend it with new widgets.

I would love one written in Node.JS, Ruby, or Python, although anything else would be fine too.

The widgets I currently use are the RSS Reader and the Note (a persistent, directly editable text field).

I have searched the web for such apps but could not find any. If there are CMS apps that can do this, I'd love to try them out.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [TiddlyWiki](http://tiddlywiki.com/). It is an open source tool for capturing, organizing and sharing information.

It is essentially written as a single page web application that can be saved locally to your desktop or device and can be hosted using Node.js if you want.

It has a very [active community](https://github.com/Jermolene/TiddlyWiki5) and has been around for 10+ years.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but an amazing app I didn't know existed. I can see some scenarios where that would be useful. Thanks for sharing!